# Writing in textarea on one page, displaying text data in another

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I am writing an app that allows users to write and title stories within two textareas (one for each). After submission, I want the title to be displayed as a link to a page that will display the user's product in header(title)/paragraph(story content) notation. As background info, so far I've used only html and css, and I'm hoping to do this with either of the two or javascript. Any help is appreciated! Apologize if this is a confusing post, this is my first!

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic. HTML is not a programming language. CSS is not a programming language. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+use+javascript+for+server+side+programming&t=hf&ia=qa

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You will need **php** to achieve it.

Go learn some stuff about it :

- Codecademy has a good interface to learn some language.
  https://www.codecademy.com/fr/tracks/php
- W3Schools is a standard for html/css/php/sql/jsjquery etc.
  https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

You can handle form with some other language, like python or javascript+nodejs. It depends of your needs. But if you are a beginner at coding, try php, you will find a lot of help on the web.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any particular part of php or node I should look in to? What exactly would it be called?

Comment: I recommend you to start with PHP, (javascript+node was just another example). And there is no particular thing to start with. You have to learn php from the start to learn variables and variables types, arrays, calculation,  basic php functions. Check my link from Codecademy. It's a lesson of 4h or so. It will give you the base to search by yourself after